# how do I use @font-face in WordPress.org?

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face

Good evening.
I have been trying to use the @font-face font on my WordPress site, I have followed some examples from W3 schools and another website about adding it into WordPress but I can not see any difference.

I am trying to apply it to the  tag but I haven't seen any change.
I have tried adding the code under additional css under the Customize menu and have also tried adding it in the style.css file.

below is the code I have been trying to use.

```
@font-face{
    font-family:h3Font;
    src:url(sensation_light.woff);
}
h3{font-family:h3Font;

}

<h3>We offer a wide range of design and marketing solutions for all types of business.
We specialise in content management systems(CMS), Responsive Website design, Ecommerce and Web development.</h3>
```

Any help on this topic would be gratefully appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your font file in the same directory with your CSS? The relative path on your code is that way. Make sure that you have the correct relative path to your font file (like ../fonts/sensation_light.woff)

Comment: I added it to the existing css file.